# Where should I put Vue.use() method in code?

Tags: vue.js

I want to use one plugin for vue and in the documentation it says I have to put in the code

```
import ReadMore from 'vue-read-more';

Vue.use(ReadMore);
```

I have no problem putting import near other imports, but where I should put the Vue.use?

here's my code structure:

```
import TextBox from '../TextBox.vue'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default{
  ready: function () {
    //stuff
  },
  data () {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    TextBox
  },
  methods: {
    sendContact: function (e) {
      //stuff
    }
  }
}
```

The application author doesn't work anymore in the company so I'm unable to ask him about the code.

Comment: Try to put where `import Vue from 'vue'` is ?

Comment: I did that too, but still have no idea where to put 'use', I tried to put it just after the import but the app crashed - no error, just blank page. PHPstorm tells me also about 'unresolvedfunction or method use()'

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but this is the most useless plugin I have ever seen. Just add a boolean to data() and add a v-on:click event to the read more link, then use v-if or v-show to show the read more text. This is like importing a library to check for an even or odd number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good thing you can do to learn about this is to install [the vue cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli), setup a new blank project, and check out how this is handled in a standard vue cli application (it is done in the `main.js` file).

In your own application, if it was generated by vue-cli (or at least it follows some standards), it is likely that `main.js` imports Vue, creates a new Vue instance and mounts it in some tag (typically `#app`).

Now, however, there could be the case that your app is not generated by vue cli or doesn't have a standard `main.js` file: this is not necessarily a bad thing, since Vue is intended to be easily plugged into an existing jQuery website or other framework driven applications. From the code you pasted, it seems that this is the case.

If so, you should search in your project for `import Vue` and `new Vue` to find the file(s) that instantiates the Vue instance. You should then call to `Vue.use()` right after Vue is imported and  before any `new Vue()` call.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of importing a library you implement this:

```
<template>

<p>
  <span>This is the first text</span><span v-show = "readMore">This is the read more text</span>
  <a v-show = "!readMore" @click = "readMore=true">Read More</a>
  <a  v-show = "readMore" @click = "readMore=false">Read Less</a>
  </p>
</template>


<script>
  import TextBox from '../TextBox.vue'
  import $ from 'jquery'

  export default{
    ready: function () {
      //stuff
    },
    data () {
      return {
        readMore: false,
        name: '',
        email: ''
      }
    },
    components: {
      TextBox
    },
    methods: {
      sendContact: function (e) {
        //stuff
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: that's actually even better and it works! Thank you a lot!